# Live agent console tabs

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console

We've implemented live agent in our org and w're hoping to be able to keep the details tab in focus when a chat session begins.

We search for a contact with the prechat api and it opens the contact record on top of the details page in an External Page tab.

[image]

Is it possible to keep the Details tab in focus and open the Contact Record tab behind it?

Comment: You can programmatically switch the focus *back*, at the very least.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the method name that does this? It looks like this person had a similar issue http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146391/how-to-choose-which-subtab-to-focus-on-with-live-agent

Comment: What you are looking for is a custom solution, like @Adrian mentioned, you need to programmatically set **focus** on the **details** tab. Check-out [Salesforce Console integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It didn't occur to me that you might not be aware of it, but you will need the **[Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm)** here.

There are four methods that will be useful for you here:

- **[`getFocusedPrimaryTabId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getfocusedprimarytabid.htm)**

  > Returns the ID of the primary tab on which the browser is focused. This method is only available in API version 25.0 or later.
- **[`getFocusedSubtabId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getfocusedprimarytabid.htm)**

  > Returns the ID of the subtab on which the browser is focused. For example, a case ID or account ID. This method is only available in API version 25.0 or later.
- **[`focusPrimaryTabById()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getfocusedprimarytabid.htm)**

  > Focuses the browser on a primary tab that is already open with the specified ID. This method is only available in API version 22.0 or later.
- **[`focusSubTabById()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getfocusedprimarytabid.htm)**

  > Focuses the browser on a subtab that is already open with the specified ID. This method is only available in API version 22.0 or later.

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to recommend how to compose these, but that should get you started.

---

You should also take a look at **[Connecting to the Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_connecting.htm)**:

> For a third-party domain:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://c.<yourInstance>.visual.force.com/support/console/39.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```
>
> For third-party domains, it’s necessary to specify an absolute URL to integration.js to use the toolkit. If you can't determine the org's instance, you can access the toolkit library at the default instance. Contact Salesforce for the default instance’s URL.

Comment: Our pre chat form is hosted on an external website. We follow this example

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_pre_chat_forms_code_sample.htm.

I dont think we'll have access to the deployment javascript library.

Comment: @Programatic You just have to do a little digging. :)